# ¿Cómo paso esta variable php ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, php7

¿Cómo paso estas dos variables que pasan en un post php al archivo normat.php?

```
$tipow2=$_POST['tipow'];
$anow2=$_POST['anow'];
```

El cual es llamado mediante este código:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                var dataTable = $('#employee-grid').DataTable( {
                  "aaSorting": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
                   "processing": true,
                    "serverSide": true,
                    "ajax":{
                        url :"normat.php", // json datasource
                        type: "post",  // method  , by default get
                        error: function(){  // error handling
                            $(".employee-grid-error").html("");
                            $("#employee-grid").append('<tbody class="employee-grid-error"><tr><th colspan="3"> No hay Información </th></tr></tbody>');
                            $("#employee-grid_processing").css("display","none");

                        }
                    }
                } );
            } );
        </script>
```

Luego en ese archivo normat.php las recibo con **Post**:

```
$tipoow = $_POST["tipow"]; 
$anoow = $_POST["anow"];
```

Y juego con ellas en las consultas:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, numero, ano, descripcion, fecha, estado, archivo, pagina, tipo";
$sql.=" FROM normativa WHERE tipo='".$tipoow."' AND ano='".$anoow."'";
```

---

si si perfecto pero ahora como paso las variables traídas del post de php a JS

```
$tipow2=$_POST['tipow'];
$anow2=$_POST['anow'];



var tipow = "contenido de tu variable $tipow2";
var anow = "contenido de tu variable $anow2";
```

he intentado asi y no me resulta

```
var tipow = '<?php echo $tipow2; ?>';
 var anow = '<?php echo $anow2; ?>';
```

pero si le escribo manualmente si funciona.. pero deseo que allí se pongan las variables traídas en post

```
var tipow = "DECRETOS";
var anow = "2017";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sin tanto lío:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            tipow:tipow,
            anow:anow
        }
        url: "normat.php",
        success: function(respuesta) {
        }
        error: function(respuesta){
        }
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

No estoy muy seguro de si comprendí bien tu consulta, pero supongo que querras decir que querés enviar las variables *tipow* y *anow* a través un AJAX para recibirlas mediante POST en *normat.php*, si es así deberías tener definidas estas dos variables declaradas y las podrías enviar con la propiedad *data*.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            var tipow = "contenido de tu variable";
            var anow = "contenido de tu variable";

            var dataTable = $('#employee-grid').DataTable( {
              "aaSorting": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
               "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                "ajax":{
                    url :"normat.php", // json datasource
                    type: "post",  // method  , by default get
                    data: {'tipow' : tipow, 'anow' : anow},
                    error: function(){  // error handling
                        $(".employee-grid-error").html("");
                        $("#employee-grid").append('<tbody class="employee-grid-error"><tr><th colspan="3"> No hay Información </th></tr></tbody>');
                        $("#employee-grid_processing").css("display","none");

                    }
                }
            } );
        } );
```

Decime si te funciona y si es lo que buscabas.

Comment: si si perfecto pero ahora como paso las variables traídas del post de php a JS $tipow2=$_POST['tipow'];
$anow2=$_POST['anow'];

aca:

var tipow = "contenido de tu variable $tipow2";
var anow = "contenido de tu variable $anow2";